# Why does stunnel keep on reading the old pem file?

Tags: ssl, stunnel

I've updated the pem file using the rekeyed certificate. But upon checking the certificate information through various SSL checkers, the old certificate was being read. I tried reloading the stunnel configuration file (stunnel /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf) but still getting the same result.

Are there any additional steps that I missed when updating the pem file using the rekeyed certificate?

Comment: When you stop 'stunnel', are there any processes of it still running in the background (i.e. ps awx | grep stunnel)?

Comment: The issue has been resolved already. Just noticed something on stunnel behavior (not sure if this is the normal thing for this). When you reload the updated config file (stunnel /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf), the previous process was not killed. It is required to kill all the processes first before starting the service again.